# Change system-wide default font for a particular language

Tags: font, internationalization, arabic

The default macOS font for Persian/Arabic is quite bad (IMO). Is it possible to change the system-wide default font for particular languages? I guess I'm looking for the [equivalent of fontconfig rules](https://github.com/omid/Persian-Calendar-for-Gnome-Shell/issues/10#issuecomment-339109199) for macOS?

I saw some [old posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/215245/471921) that disable SIP for this. Is this still the only way?

Comment: Even disabling SIP may not be enough, as Apple makes such things harder every year.  You should try what is given in  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215245/how-to-change-default-fallback-font-for-non-latin-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1  and then post there to tell everyone whether it still work or not.

Comment: It does not work. The `DefaultFontFallbacks.plist` doesn't seem to exist in recent versions anyway. Wrote about it here: https://mil.ad/blog/2022/persian-font-macos.html